# Access Privileges of Files

Tags: java, wildfly-8, file-access

We have a Java bean writing files via `Files.write` into the Wildfly's data folder, and for whatever reason the new file sometimes gets entirely wrong access privileges and can not be read from anybody.

I haven't been able to reproduce this error, and am just guessing what's happening and know most of the problems only from hearsay.

We tried setting the new file's owner like that, figuring if the server was the owner of it, the error would go away:

```
Path newFile = ...
Path dir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));
UserPrincipal user = Files.getOwner(dir);
Files.setOwner(newFile, user);
```

This sometimes sprouted `AccessDeniedException`.

Then we tried setting the privileges directly:

```
File file = newFile.toFile();
file.setReadable(true, false);
file.setWritable(true, false);
file.setExecutable(true, false);
```

This did nothing at all.

Finally we tried to set the ACL like this:

```
Path folder = Paths.get(jbossDataDir);
AclFileAttributeView folderAttributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(folder, AclFileAttributeView.class);

AclFileAttributeView fileAttributes = Files.getFileAttributeView(newFile, AclFileAttributeView.class);
fileAttributes.setAcl(folderAttributes.getAcl());
```

But as before, sometimes nobody can access the file any more. The broken files have the following permissions (whatever that means) and can't be opened via double click either:

```
BUILTIN\Administratoren:(F)
BUILTIN\Administratoren:(OI)(CI)(IO)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(M)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(DE)
BUILTIN\Benutzer:(RX)
BUILTIN\Benutzer:(OI)(CI)(IO)
```

And the JBoss data folder has the following permissions:

```
Everyone:(OI)(CI)(M)
BUILTIN\Benutzer:(OI)(CI)(M)
Everyone:(I)(OI)(CI)(M)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administratoren:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Benutzer:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
BUILTIN\Benutzer:(I)(CI)(AD)
BUILTIN\Benutzer:(I)(CI)(WD)
CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

At this point I'm thankful for anything, even if it's "just" being able to reproduce the original bug. Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: What filesystem you are using? Which file is `newFile`? What are the permissions on `jbossDataDir`? Have you logged the values of `newFile` and `jbossDataDir` to check if not one of them pointing to a wrong place?

Comment: @SubOptimal File system: NTFS. newFile is the file we create manually. jbossDataDir has all permissions except for "full access", "change permissions" and "take ownership" (roughly translated). And yes, the files are pointing to the right direction.

Comment: How does the computer which is sending the file interact with your bean? Webinterface, RMI, ...?

Comment: @SubOptimal Both RMI and REST webinterface, and as far as I know the error exists for both.

Comment: Then the following isn't possible. `REST interface` and `can only be read from the computer that originally sent the file`. If the remote computer is using the REST interface to access your bean, the application server can't know (except you do something strange) the remote computer users permissions.

Comment: @SubOptimal You are right, evidently _nobody_ can access the file.

Comment: What permissions the file get if you don't alter them? Simply stored it with the bean.

Comment: What are the permissions of `jbossDataDir`?

Comment: @SubOptimal Thanks for your continuous effort, I added that as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you should

- either review the user permissions he inherit from the groups he is member
- or check if the file is exclusively locked by another process (Virusscaner, etc.)
- or compare the ACL for the files which are accessible / unaccessible

Based on your posted ACLs I would say...

If the user try to access the file on the same PC logged in with a local user account (BUILTIN\Benutzer) he has all appropriate rights to modify the file.

If the user try to access the file from a remote PC logged in with a domain user account (NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users) he has all appropriate right to modify the file too.

Which looks ok for me.